# My friend can't join my server

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod

My friend can't join my dedicated server and when he tried he got a message says "Server is not responding", do I have to port forwarding my router?
I was trying to, but the options I have in mine are this:

Type:
Protocol:
Remote host:
Remote port range:
Local host:
Local port:
Status:

so what should I type?

Answer (score 0):

You should do port forwarding on your router to allow connection to your friend.
For that you should enter the following information:

1. Service Type: BOTH TCP and UDP (Usually Listed as TCP/UDP)
2. Starting Port: 27015
3. Ending Port: 27015
4. local host : The ip address of your server, usually the one of your computer if the server is on your computer.
5. You do not need to fill in Remote host